# How do I use Ajax in a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with 2 dropdown boxes. When I select an option in the first dropdown box I want the 2nd one to be refreshed with data from a PHP function. For that I need ajax. But I'm struggling with binding ajax into Wordpress.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/">
    <div class="form-inner">   
       <div class="listing-search-main">
            <input type="text" class="listing-search-text text" name="s" title="Coach House, Golf Course, Water View, etc" value="unique">
            <input type="submit" class="listing-search-submit btn btn-large btn-primary" name="search-submit" value="Search">
            </div><!-- .listing-search-main -->

       <div class="listing-search-details">
           <div class="listing-search-field listing-search-field-select listing-search-field-status">
           <select class="listing-search-status select" name="status">
              <option value="">Status</option>
              <option value="sale">Sales</option>
              <option value="rent">Rentals</option>
              <option value="foreclosure">Foreclosure</option>
           </select>

      <div class="listing-search-advanced " style="display: block;">
          <div class="listing-search-field listing-search-field-select listing-search-field-min">
           <select class="listing-search-min select" name="min">
              <option value="">Price (min)</option>
              <option value="100000">100.000</option>
              <option value="200000">200.000</option>
              <option value="300000">300.000</option>
              <option value="400000">400.000</option>
           </select>
```

Now when for example the user selects "Sales" I want the second select tag to be reloaded with the matching prices from a PHP array.

The PHP function looks like this:

```
 <?php

$selectedStatus = $_POST['status'];


if($selectedStatus == "sale")
{

    // Set price (min) to select

    $fields['min']['type'] = 'select';

    // Set price (min) select options
    $fields['min']['data'] = array(
        '100000' => '120,000',
        '120000' => '200.000',
        '130000' => '300.000',
    );

    // Set price (max) to select

    $fields['max']['type'] = 'select';

    // Set price (max) select options

    $fields['max']['data'] = array(
        '100000' => '120,000',
        '120000' => '200.000',
        '130000' => '300.000',
    );


}
else if($selectedStatus == "rent")
    {

        // Set price (min) to select

        $fields['min']['type'] = 'select';

        // Set price (min) select options
        $fields['min']['data'] = array(
            '200' => '200',
        );

        // Set price (max) to select

        $fields['max']['type'] = 'select';

        // Set price (max) select options

        $fields['max']['data'] = array(
            '200' => '200',
        );

    }

echo $fields;
```

I've save my jQuery Ajax call in a separate .js file. The code is the following:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".listing-search-status.select[name='status']").change(function() {

        if (this.value == "sale")
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/wp-content/plugins/wpcasa-extended-search-status-price-chain-select/wpcasa_custom_prices.php",
                    data: { status : "sale" },
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                      alert('Sale' + data['min']['data'][0]);
                    }
                     });
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.value == "rent")
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/wp-content/plugins/wpcasa-extended-search-status-price-chain-select/wpcasa_custom_prices.php",
                    data: { status : "rent" },
                                            success: function(data) 
                        {
                       alert('Rent' + data['min']['data'][0]);
                        }
                                     });
            }
        }

  });
 });
```

But the alert Boxes don't show up. Neither do I get any error messages on Google Chrome's Console. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the native methods that Wordpress provides to you to leverage ajax requests.

In your plugin file, we need to add a couple actions so that we can send ajax requests through and have them parsed by the `admin-ajax.php` file.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'ajax_controller');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'ajax_controller');
```

Now we build out an ajax controller in our plugin file. The purpose of this is to act as a controller that will switch it's output based on the `FN` parameter supplied by the `ajax` request (more on this later)

```
function ajax_controller(){
    $ret = ''; //our return variable
    switch($_REQUEST['fn']):
        case 'status' :
            $ret = update_status($_REQUEST['status']);
            break;
    endswitch;
    echo $ret;
    die(); //this makes sure you don't get a "1" or "0" appended to the end of your request.
}
```

Please note that the `update_status()` function was created to encapsulate your above php code.

Now we have the actions bound, and a controller that we can use endlessly to retrieve data. We just need to make a couple modifications to the ajax call. First, we can use ternary assignment for the 'rent/sale' switch, as opposed to 2 ajax calls, which will clean things up. Second, we need to change the url address to the `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` file.

```
var $status = (this.value == "sale") ? this.value : 'rent';
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: { 
       action: 'ajax_request', 
       fn : 'status', //this is the $_REQUEST['fn'] from above
       status : $status },
    success: function(data){
        alert('Sale' + data['min']['data'][0]);
    }
});
```

The `action` parameter is required, the `fn` is a result of my coding principles. The `action` attribute must directly match what comes after `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_` and `add_action('wp_ajax_`.

This should resolve it.