# PHP - Get contents of div generated by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I have the following div that has a number generated by jQuery:

HTML:

```
<td id="Total" class="total">
</td>
```

jQuery:

```
var sum = 0;
$(".item-price").each(function() {
    var NewQuoteTotal = $(this).html().replace('£', '')
    sum += parseInt(NewQuoteTotal);
})
console.log(sum)
$(".total").text('£' + sum)
```

I need to get the generated number from that element so that I can use it in PHP to be displayed elsewhere.

I've meddled with DOM (Which I don't know):

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$html = file_get_contents("FILELOCATION"); //I don't use FILELOCATION, that's just a placeholder for StackOverflow.
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$thePrice = $dom->getElementById("Total");
if(!$thePrice) {
    die("Element Not Found!");
}
echo "Element is there!";
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//td[id="Total"]');
echo $divContent;
```

And tried to use jQuery to $.post() a variable containing the number but I've had no success.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.post('/path/to/my/php/script.php', {total: $('#Total').text()}, function(){
    //what to do with the returned data from the server
});
```

And in `script.php` (as indicated above):

```
$total = isset($_POST['total']) ?: false;
if($total !== false):
    //you can use $total now
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this before but it seemed to not work because my PHP script and the `"total" td` were in the same file.

Comment: @Mallander place the code I've supplied above the rest of the data in that page then, and change the path to `'/'`

Comment: I'm using Xampp to host the local server (And Wordpress), so using '/' is sending it back to the xampp root. Also if I use the exact filepath then I'm getting a wordpress error with an undefined get_header() function.

Comment: @Mallahander Ah, I see, so the issue is that this is within a Wordpress environment, then? [See my answer on how to use AJAX in Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092165/how-do-i-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin/24092293#24092293)

Comment: I've looked through your other answer but i can't see how I can change that to work with mine, mainly because I don't understand what you've done there :P

Comment: I'm getting this error: <b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'ajax_controller' not found or invalid function name in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PMD-new/wp-includes/plugin.php</b> on line <b>470</b><br />

Comment: @Mallandar place the code into your functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I didn't think of it earlier, but I just made the variable in PHP rather than jQuery...

Thanks for all the help!